# c++ Dialog box doesn't render properly on PC screen

Tags: c++, resources, desktop, visual-studio-2010

I have dialog window specified via a *.rc file that doesn't render properly on the screen.  It exhibits the following set of anomalies:

1. The dialog window is white.
2. The dialog window title bar is absent.
3. All GUI objects are rendered two times -- once at position (X,Y) specified by the *.rc file and a 2nd time at position (X+3,Y+23).  Pushbuttons at position (X,Y) are alive.  The "echoes" at (X+3,Y+23) are non-functional.
4. The pushbutton object specified as DEFPUSHBUTTON is not the default pushbutton, and the pushbutton object specified as PUSHBUTTON is the default pushbutton.

Other than the default pushbutton anomaly and the weird appearance, the Dialog window operates as it should, as does the callback function -- SelectPuzzle() -- that it invokes.   The source code for SelectPuzzle() is not enclosed but is available upon request as are screen shots.

This code is virtually identical to code I have used successfully in other projects.  Why it doesn't work here remains a mystery.  Can anyone help?

I've tried everything I can think of to diagnose this bug but without success, e.g.:

1. In place of DialogBoxParam(), I tried using DialogBox() with variable PuzzleDB supplied as a global.  Same result.
2. I tried stripped-down, simplified versions both of the resource file and of the SelectPuzzle() function, 
   --  i.e., a DIALOGEX resource with just a "Cancel" pushbutton and a SelectPuzzle() function with just an empty WM_INITDIALOG section and a WM_COMMAND case to support the Cancel pushbutton. Same result.
3. I verified consistent use of the IDD_SELECTPUZZLE constant in MainApp and in resource file.  I also tried different numeric values for IDD_SELECTPUZZLE.
   Same result.

The following code excerpts are relevant:

```
MainApp.h    (included in stdafx.h)                                                      
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                          
#define IDD_SELECTPUZZLE   9500                                                              
#define IDM_SelectPuzzle   9510                                                              
#define ID_CurrentPuzzle   9521                                                              
#define ID_SelectedPuzzle  9522                                                              
#define ID_PuzzleSelStatus 9523                                                              
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                                                                                                                   

PuzzleDB.h   (included in stdafx.h)                                                      

//=======================================================================                
// PuzzleDB.h : Defines the entry point for the application.                             
//=======================================================================                    
#pragma once                                                                             

typedef struct {                                                                             
    int NumberOfPuzzles;                                                                        
    int *PuzzleNumbers;                                                                         
    int ndxCurrentPuzzleNumber;                                                                   
    clasPuzzle *Puzzle;                                                                         
} PuzzleSelectionData, *pPuzzleSelectionData;                                                

clasPuzzle *ResetPuzzle(                                                                     
    clasPuzzle *Puzzle                                                                          
  );    

char *LoadPuzzle(                                                                            
    char *tstr                                                                                   
  , int ndxSelectedPuzzle                                                                      
  , pPuzzleSelectionData pPuzzleDB );                                                                                     


MainApp.cpp,                                                                             

#include "stdafx.h"                                                                          
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                            
LRESULT CALLBACK  WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);                                       
INT_PTR CALLBACK  SelectPuzzle(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);                                  
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                            
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)              
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                            
  static PuzzleSelectionData PuzzleDB;                                                         
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                            
  switch (message)                                                                             
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                            
    case WM_COMMAND:                                                                             
      switch (wParam)                                                                      
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                            
        //*****WM_COMMAND********************************************            
        case IDM_SelectPuzzle:                                                                       
          k = PuzzleDB.ndxCurrentPuzzleNumber;                                                         
          DialogBoxParam(                                                                              
              hInst                                                                                        
            , MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SELECTPUZZLE)        
            , hWnd, SelectPuzzle                                                                         
            , (unsigned long)(&PuzzleDB));                                                               
          if (PuzzleDB.ndxCurrentPuzzleNumber != k)                                                    
            SendMessage(hWnd,WM_COMMAND,IDM_LoadPuzzle,0L);                              
          break;                                                                         
  .                                                                                      
  .                                                                                                                                                                                  
AppName.rc                                                                               
  .                                                                                     
  .                                                                                      
//**** BEGIN Application specific resources *********************************            
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
// Application specific resource.                                                        
// Menu Dialog item "Select Puzzle"                                                      
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
IDD_SELECTPUZZLE DIALOGEX 4, 4, 126, 74 // Position w.r.t. parent window.                
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU      
CAPTION "Select Puzzle"                                                                  
FONT 10, "MS Shell Dlg"                                                                  
BEGIN                                                                                    
  ICON            IDR_MAINFRAME             , IDC_STATIC        ,14,14, 21,20            
  LTEXT "Use Mouse Wheel to Select Puzzle." , IDC_STATIC        , 8, 4,118,12,SS_NOPREFIX
  LTEXT           "Current Puzzle:  "       , IDC_STATIC        , 8,16, 52,12,SS_NOPREFIX
  LTEXT           "New Selection:   "       , IDC_STATIC        , 8,28, 52,12,SS_NOPREFIX
  PUSHBUTTON      "Accept"                  , ID_OK             , 8,40, 52, 4,WS_GROUP   
  DEFPUSHBUTTON   "CANCEL"                  , ID_CANCEL         ,66,40, 52, 4,WS_GROUP   
  LTEXT           "                 "       , ID_CurrentPuzzle  ,66,16, 52,12,SS_NOPREFIX
  LTEXT           "                 "       , ID_SelectedPuzzle ,66,28, 52,12,SS_NOPREFIX
  LTEXT           "                 "       , ID_PuzzleSelStatus, 8,60,110,12,SS_NOPREFIX
  END                                                                                    
//**** END Application specific resources ***********************************
```

Comment: sounds like something in WM_PAINT-handling

Comment: Thank you for your response.  In my limited experience I've seen WM_PAINT used only in the WndProc of the main app -- not in a dialog function such as 
INT_PTR CALLBACK  SelectPuzzle(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
If I were to add WM_PAINT to the dialog function, what lines of code would it execute?

Comment: if you don't handle `WM_PAINT` then no problem there. Post a **complete but minimal** example.

Comment: I have created a "Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example" that meets StackOverflow reqmts.
All relevant source has been collected in a zip-file. 
QUESTION:  Rather than post all of this code in a comment, is there some way I can transmit these files to you or to StackOverflow -- i.e., as attachments to my comment, email?   
I researched this QUESTION on website and came up empty.   
I could concatenate all of the source, shifted to right by 4 spaces, and post, but that would exceed the # of characters limit.

Comment: How about, maybe, post a link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I hadn't previously heard of gist.  Like StackOverflow.com, it too appears to limit content to the body of the gist and not support attachments. 
For simplicity and clerical accuracy I would prefer simply to attach my files to an email.  
Can you supply an email address by which I can send you these files?  E.g., even a temporary gmail or hotmail acct would suffice.

Comment: It would be preferable to reduce the example to something that can be accessed as a gist (just a few pure text files), but otherwise, why not create a zip and put it on [Google drive](http://drive.google.com), or if not that, consider e.g. creating a project at [Google Code](http://code.google.com) and anyway, post the link here so that people (not necessarily me) can answer? Note that for a Visual Studio project, if it's that, you can just delete the huge binary files. They will be regenerated. You only need the project and solution files, and the source code (try it).

Comment: I have posted the code for my MCT&R example to Google code and shared same for those with the link.  The link is:

https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B0RSHjLVgCpDeDRDdWYxcExDR28

Let me know if you cannot access these files.  

Thank you for your assistance with this.

Comment: The link is to an inaccessible folder on Google Drive (formerly Google Documents).

Comment: The relevant directory on Google Drive has been shared.  Sorry about the oversight.

Comment: 150 MB is quite a lot for a minimal example. I hope that not all of that is source code… Oh sorry, Google Docs had decided to download a lot more, but still, 8.5 MB is too much. You can always just delete the .sdf file.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you return `TRUE` from the dialog procedure for all messages. Except for a handful of special messages, this indicates that you don't want default handling. Thus things that should be done, are not being done.

Tip for dialogs: seriously underdocumented, but where you need to return some specific value for some specific message, use `SetDlgMsgResult` from `<windowsx.h>`, or equivalent code.

---

In passing, the code can be greatly simplified and improved by

- removing use of Visual C++ non-standard semantics precompiled headers (for standard-conformance and maintainability),
- removing use of Visual C++ non-standard `tWinMain`, just use standard `main`,
- removing use of Windows 9x support (the unmentionably silly Microsoft `T` stuff for strings),
- using `std::wstring` instead of C library string handling,
- and using wide string literals instead of narrow ones plus conversion,
- etc.

---

A particularly bad apple, in the `tWinMain` function this code:

```
  if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
```

1. `InitInstance` only makes sense for 16-bit Windows.
2. passing `nCmdShow` around only makes sense for 16-bit Windows (in 32-bit Windows it is *ignored* by the first `ShowWindow` call).
3. Returning `FALSE` here erroneously indicates success, when it is a failure.

I have seen essentially this code many times, even in the D language's Windows support, and I suspect that it originates with Microsoft.

Anyway, wherever you got that from, that source is seriously outdated *and* unreliable, to be treated only as a source of bad programming habits and ingenious ways to introduce bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info, which I will try to digest.  I
appreciate your candor.  I am a relative newbee to VS 2010 C++ Express, following a 20-year hiatus from C++ programming back when the language was a much simpler beast.

To answer your question, I developed my source largely by making minimal modifications to code that is auto-generated by VS 2010 C++ Express when a new win32 project is created -- primarily the main source module and the resource file.  
However, my weakness for narrow strings and non-use of 
SetDlgMsgResult is (was) my own Luddite thinking.

Comment: Oh. You might find my old [tutorial on Windows API programming](http://learnwinapi.wordpress.com/) helpful. It was written at the time of Visual C++ 2010. Only finished six installments or so, but should get you up and running, I think. :-)

Comment: SUCCESS! 
The key was in your suggestion regarding my overuse of 
   return (INT_PTR)TRUE
at the end of my SelectPuzzle function.  
I modified SelectPuzzle.cpp and cleared all anomalies. 

I changed the last such statement in that function to 

   return (INT_PTR)FALSE
   
and deleted the two identical statements immediately above. 
That fix eliminated Anomalies 1 thru 3 in my original post. 

I then added case WM_CHAR: and case WM_EXIT: in the message 
switch statement to SendMessage(hDlg,WM_COMMAND,ID_CANCEL,0L);
That fix eliminated Anomaly 4.

Issue is SOLVED.  Thanks for your support.